# Rails 4: Submitting array of related objects in form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

This has become a question regarding how Rails seems to magically know to create join table records without me specifying it to create those records.

I'm building an e-commerce solution where users can buy packages, and within those packages are a number of items. I created a form to handle the creation of a package that also allows you to add the items you want to put inside that package in the same form.

To accomplish this, I created a `package` model, `item` model and a `package_item` model that joins the two (not every item belongs to a package and I want users to be able to add additional items not included in the package, so I thought this would be the best way to relate the two).

My thought process was to create checkboxes for the items available to add to the package and submit those as an array, and then add the items array as a permitted parameter in the strong parameters method in the package controller.

Here's my form from app/views/packages/_form.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for(@package) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <h3>Items:</h3>
      <% @items.each do |item| %>
        <%= check_box_tag :item_ids, item.id, @package.package_items.include?(item), name: 'package[item_ids][]' %>
        <!-- somehow, this displays the items correctly and allows me to submit them as an array -->

      <% end %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

packages_controller (without the actions not related to my question):

```
class PackagesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_package, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @packages = Package.all
  end

  def new
    @package = Package.new
    @items = Item.all
  end

  def create
    @package = Package.new(package_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @package.save
        # I thought the next block would be necessary, but apparently it isn't
        # package_params[:item_ids].each do |item|
          # @package.package_items.build(item_id: item)
        # end
        format.html { redirect_to @package, notice: 'package was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @package }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @package.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_package
      @package = Package.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def package_params
      params.require(:package).permit(:name, :description, :item_ids => [])
    end    
end
```

<del>To handle the creation of the package items, after the package is created, I iterate over the array of items, creating a new `@package.package_items` record for each item.</del>

**UPDATE:**
The commented out code in the above code block is what I originally thought I would need to include so as to create the join table records. However, I found when running that code that I was creating duplicate records. So I removed that block and realized Rails somehow intuitively knows to go ahead and create the `package_items` records when an array of item IDs is included in the params. Can anyone explain how Rails knows how to do this?

I'm also curious if there are 'better' or more efficient ways to accomplish what I'm doing here. Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Here are my models for reference:

package.rb:

```
class Package < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items, through: :package_items
  has_many :package_items
end
```

item.rb:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :package_items
  has_many :packages, through: :package_items
end
```

package_item.rb:

```
class PackageItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :package
  belongs_to :item
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've come along way since this question. The answer is inside `package_params` - I'm sending the `item_ids` in through the permitted params. My model `has_many :items, through: :package_items`, which allows me to do this and automatically create the related objects.